# Google CustomSearchEngine: How to get whole ArticleBody?

Tags: json, google-api-java-client, google-custom-search

I use CSE to crawl websites which publish news in form of articles, blogs, etc.

Link to my CSE: https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=003284443790305850415:xbxu60ofaec.

My job is to implement a program to extract the results in JSON-format and analyze the articlebody. Unfortunatelly the articlebody (attribute/value pair) gets shortened automatically, so I don't get the whole articlebody at all. For instance:

> "articlebody": "How to Exploit Routers on an Unrooted Android Phone RouterSploit is a powerful exploit framework similar to Metasploit, working to quickly identify and exploit common vulnerabilities in routers...."

Is there a way to get the whole articlebody in JSON?

My code for now:

```
public class CustomSearchAPI {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String key="AIzaSyALOC-8_qk_IrT3MEx8JzQ2MmXPbtlBhJw";
    String qry="exploit";
    URL url = new URL(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+ "&cx=003284443790305850415:xbxu60ofaec&q="+ qry + "&alt=json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));


    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    conn.disconnect();
}


}
```

My dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-customsearch</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev56-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```